# Laravel: Using increment ID for another columns default value

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have (doesn't work because $id is not actually the generated id):

```
Schema::create('threads', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $id = $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('base64_id', 6)->default(Math::to_base($id, 62))
    });
```

My question is how I can get the currently generated id to be $id, so I can generate another ID by using the ID.

Comment: Please read your question before you post it.

Comment: I want $id to be the id that is being automatically generated for that row to use it to calculate a custom id.

Comment: exactly.. in case MySQL calculates the id only for inserting it would have to be done after via updating after inserting, so I cannot use a default value for that?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Also, would you mind showing the code you have for the `to_base()` method?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible using migrations, but you can use [a `created` event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events) on your model that fills in this field every time a new row is created.

For example:

```
namespace App\Observers;

use App\Thread;

class ThreadObserver
{
    public function created(Thread $thread)
    {
        $thread->base64_id = base64_encode($thread->id);
        $thread->save();
    }
}
```